# Как обнулить значение AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: php, kohana, mysql

Нагуглил, что для обнуления AUTO_INCREMENT нужен следующий запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE <имя таблицы> AUTO_INCREMENT=0
```

Как этот запрос написать в `Kohana` при помощи модуля `ORM`?

Comment: А зачем вам это, можно поинтересоваться?

Comment: Есть древовидное меню, которое хранится в БД. Его необходимо обновлять полностью с xml  документа. Самое простое решение - снести всю таблицу, и ввести все значения из xml. Только вот хотел, что бы без удаления и создания новой таблицы

Comment: А отказаться от AUTO_INCREMENT и самому генерировать id, не вариант?

Comment: Может это и не логично... Спорить не буду)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Помог обычный mysql

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234');
            mysql_select_db('al_categories');
            $query = 'ALTER TABLE al_categories AUTO_INCREMENT=4';
            mysql_query($query);
            mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 2):

А вообще, как-то так не пойдёт?

```
DB::query(null, 'ALTER TABLE <имя таблицы> AUTO_INCREMENT=0');
```

Comment: без результата (

Answer (score 0):

У меня ни один из этих способов не работает. Даже Truncate не обнуляет счетчик.

Нашел выход:

Заходим непосредственно в phpMyAdmin, заходим в таблицу. Там в меню заходим в операции и там во втором столбце(Table options(место, где меняет название таблицы, кодировку и тд.)) Auto_increment меняем на 1 в ручную.

И все шикарно наботает.

Версия phpMyAdmin 4.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть данные в таблице, то вы не можете сбросить AUTO_INCREMENT.
Потому что могут быть коллизии, полностью одинаковые строки.
Вы можете удалить столбец с AI, а потом создать заново.
Если же таблица пуста, и первый элемент идет не с единицы, а с другого, то самый просто способ это использовать Workbench

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -2):

```
TRUNCATE <table_name>
```

Очищает таблицу, но так же сбрасывает счётчик.